# Auto Increment two fields in SQL?

Tags: php, sql

I was wondering if there is a way to Auto Increment two columns in the same table.

I have database with user_id so every registred user would have his unique nr.
But I want to add a file_id so every file the user upload gets a unique number.

Any tips ?
Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: The uploaded files should be contained in a separate table

Comment: I was thinking about another table, but its quite small project.
using PHPadmin

Comment: If it is SQL, try setting IDENTITY for column.

Comment: @FelipeOtarola doesnt matter how small the project is - should always be normalised -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization - if you use the correct indexes all queries will be efficient

Comment: Then Ill go for the separate table :)
Thanks

Comment: @Shailesh: SQL is the language. MySQL and SQL-Server (which has `IDENTITY`) are products (DBMS) that use SQL (actually every DBMS has it's own dialect of SQL, with more or less differences vs. the standard)

Comment: Agreed, my intention was MSSQL server rather than SQL :). Hope you took it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

To ensure your database is normalized correctly, you should store file uploads in a separate table.

This means one user has the potential to have multiple files and allows the table to correctly increment the identity field of the file records.

You can read about database normalization on Wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 1):

No, only one identity column per table is allowed.

if you are using SQl Server follow this:

If your second field is static (you dont have to edit and it follows a sinmple logic to generate its value) 
what you can do is create the second field as a calculated one, for example:

```
create table autoINC(
field1 int identity(1,1),
field2 as field1+1,
real_field varchar(50))

insert into autoINC values('test')
select * from autoINC 

1   2   test
```

if you need to update your second field, then you need to use a trigger

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a trigger or similar solution depending on the database.

In MSSQL a trigger on update should work.

But this will not ensure unique file names unless the filename also includes the userid.

Is there a reason you need fileid to be sequential for each user?

If not, add a userid field to the file table and have a separate fileid identity column in that.